# How to start iteration from outer loop?

Tags: java, arrays, selenium, loops, selenium-webdriver

I would like to iterate two nested loops in selenium. In below example, once the first iteration finishes, I would like to start my next iteration from " outerLoop: for(long l : placeHolder) " instead of " innerLoop: for(String m: nickName) ". I dont want my innerloop to finish completely and then go to outerloop. I want my outerloop to take value at index 1 from an array "placeHolder" and I want my inner loop to take value at index 1 from an array "nickName" and then go back to outerloop take value at index 2 from an array "placeHolder" and take value at index2 from an array "nickName". Below is my code.

```
long[] placeHolder = {12345678901L, 123525212101L};
String[] nickName = {"MyName","YourName"};

outerLoop: for(long l : placeHolder) {
     innerLoop: for(String m: nickName) {
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name= 'ctl00$BodyContentPlaceHolder$"+ l +"TXT']")).sendKeys(m);

     }
}
```

Comment: Have a look at `break`.

Comment: I did but it didnt work.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to iterate through the inner loop, then do not have an inner loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < placeHolder.length && i < nickName.length; i++) {
    String output = "placeHolder=" + placeHolder[i] + ",name=" + nickName[i];
    System.out.println (output);
}
```

You explanation is a bit unclear, so maybe I am missing something ?

Comment: nickName is a string data type and placeHolder is a long data type.

Comment: Yes, that is fine with my code, although your snippet of code does not explain how you will use the data in the Arrays.  Does my code work for you?

Comment: Nope. It didnt. So my use case is I have one line of code which uses two variables. The value I am giving it to my variables is coming from two arrays. So for variable1 I have to get value from Array1 at an index[0] and for variable2 I have to get value from Array2 at an index[0] of Array2. Both this variables are going into one line of code. Please let me know what part is unclear.

Comment: I have edited my answer, which will hopefully clear things up.